# Unzipping a file from InputStream and returning another InputStream

Tags: java, zip, stream

I am trying to write a function which will accept an `InputStream` with zipped file data and would return another `InputStream` with unzipped data.

The zipped file will only contain a single file and thus there is no requirement of creating directories, etc...

I tried looking at `ZipInputStream` and others but I am confused by so many different types of streams in Java.

Comment: What did you already try? Please add some code example.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**Concepts**

[GZIPInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html) is for streams (or files) zipped as gzip (".gz" extension). It doesn't have any header information.

> This class implements a stream filter for reading compressed data in the GZIP file format

If you have a real zip file, you have to use [ZipFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) to open the file, ask for the list of files (one in your example) and ask for the decompressed input stream.

Your method, if you have the file, would be something like:

```
// ITS PSEUDOCODE!!

private InputStream extractOnlyFile(String path) {
   ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(path);
   Enumeration e = zf.entries();
   ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement(); // your only file
   return zf.getInputStream(entry);
}
```

**Reading an InputStream with the content of a .zip file**

Ok, if you have an InputStream you can use (as @cletus says) ZipInputStream. It reads a stream including header data.

> ZipInputStream is for a stream with [header information + zippeddata]

**Important: if you have the file in your PC you can use `ZipFile` class to access it randomly**

This is a sample of reading a zip-file through an InputStream:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("c:/inas400.zip");

        // this is where you start, with an InputStream containing the bytes from the zip file
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(fis);
        ZipEntry entry;
            // while there are entries I process them
        while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println("entry: " + entry.getName() + ", " + entry.getSize());
                    // consume all the data from this entry
            while (zis.available() > 0)
                zis.read();
                    // I could close the entry, but getNextEntry does it automatically
                    // zis.closeEntry()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I corrected the code, the ZipInputStream had to wrap the original input stream :). Thanx!

Comment: Helios: zipinput.getNextEntry() will return a ZipEntry object. How do I convert it into a stream?

Comment: zipinputstream represents an inputstream of the unzipped data of the file. That's why I'm returning "zipinput". But it has to read the headers and position at the beginning of the current zipped data to start. That's why I first call "getnextentry". To make the zipinputstream read that header and prepare to unzip its entry (and of course, to know the zipped filename :).

Comment: Helios: Thanks for your input so far. I have a question, when you just do a `zis.read()` where does the data go? My zip file will contain only one file in it and I just want to return a stream of the uncompressed file data.

Comment: Oh, ok. zis.read() (as any InputStream.read) returns (and move forward) one byte. The other read functions work the same way reading more bytes at once. In you case you only have to: 1) get the first entry (it is... don't use a while loop) 2) return the very "zis" object: because it IS the uncompressed input stream you need. The code that works for you is the second block (the first EDIT)

Comment: Hi. Your solution is too complex and confuses people. See this answer and edit your post please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233555/is-it-possible-to-get-a-zipentrys-inputstream-from-a-zipinputstream/3233600#3233600

Comment: I've cleaned up the answer a little bit. Separated the "concept" part (the OP asks about what purpose are the different classes for) and the "read from a zip-file inputstream" part (the OP needs to read an stream containing not just gzipped data but the whole content of a zip-file).

Answer (score 7):

If you can change the input data I would suggested you to use `GZIPInputStream`.

`GZipInputStream` is different from `ZipInputStream` since you only have one data inside it. So the whole input stream represents the whole file. In `ZipInputStream` the whole stream contains also the structure of the file(s) inside it, which can be many.

Comment: The file is not in my control. It's a file that I download from a server. I used to save it to disk and then unzip it, but now I am thinking about unzipping it in memory.

Comment: What matters isn't really if the bytes originate from a network socket or from a file. The distinction to be made is between a zip archive and a blob of compressed data. If you wrote and read the data, perhaps you wouldn't really care about the archive with it's metadata, and then GZipStream would be the one to go for. You are clearly receiving an archive (or else saving it to a file and unzipping it would probably fail, at least if you unzip by running a "standard" unzip program). You can indeed unzip it in memory, using ZipInputStream.

Answer (score 6):

It is on scala syntax:

```
def unzipByteArray(input: Array[Byte]): String = {
    val zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(input))
    val entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry
    IOUtils.toString(zipInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
}
```

Comment: This scala code is helpful to unzip java.io.InputStream but it isn't using the defined 'entry' to get the next file nor does it have a close method at the end?

Comment: @puligun Yes. You are right and it is just an answer to the question.
Surely, we have to close the stream later. In other words, it is a method that you can use inside your needed case.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something, you should absolutely try and get [`ZipInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) to work and there's no reason it shouldn't (I've certainly used it on several occasions).

What you should do is try and get `ZipInputStream` to work and if you can't, post the code and we'll help you with whatever problems you're having.

Whatever you do though, don't try and reinvent its functionality.

Comment: To be fair, `java.util.zip` is a pretty unpleasant API

Comment: @skaffman yeah, you'd think they'd have a `ZipFile.unzip(destDir)` method, huh? Or a way to find entries by name/pattern easily. This API is pretty gross.